# Livestreaming to ROKU channel from VIMEO

Tags: vimeo, live-streaming, roku

I've built a ROKU channel (Custom SDK) using the "Instant TV Channel for Roku" site.  Recorded video is hosted on a VIMEO pro account and working perfectly.

I'm looking for directions to live stream from Vimeo to our Roku channel.  Simply using the live stream URL in place of a recorded video URL does not work.

Thanks in advance!
Mitch

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply, vbuchii.  

Unfortunately, this may not work for us.  It seems that Vimeo's live API is available only to Vimeo Enterprise customers.  Our account is only Vimeo Premium.  It also appears that some custom code would be needed in the package file we upload to the Roku developer site, which the "Instant TV Channel for Roku" site doesn't seem to support.

We'll continue to explore other options to get our live stream onto Roku.

Sincerely,
Mitch Kazel
University of Illinois

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a stream URL you would need to get it according to the [Vimeo API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/live/playback#playing-a-live-event-hls-step-3).

If you already requested the stream URL but it doesn't work for you, I would suggest checking it in the [Roku Stream Tester](https://devtools.web.roku.com/#stream-tester-tool). If it plays in Stream Tester but doesn't work in the app - the issue is in your code.
If doesn't work in Stream Tester - the issue is in Stream URL.

I hope it helps, let me know if you have further questions